# How to replace "fmod()" by integer "mod()" function

Tags: c++, performance, modulo

My program is having a performance drop, due to the function `fmod()` who is called lots of times, and now I'm experimenting with a workaround (using integer `mod`, in C++ written as `%`):

```
  double a,b,d;
  a = 10 * sqrt(2);
  b = PI;
  time_t result;

  result = time(NULL);
  printf("Time fmod: [%s]\n", asctime(localtime(&result)));

  for (int i = 0;i < 1000000000; i++) {
    d = fmod(a,b);
  }
  result = time(NULL);
  printf("Time fmod: [%s]\n", asctime(localtime(&result)));

  result = time(NULL);
  printf("Time integer: [%s]\n", asctime(localtime(&result)));
  for (int i = 0;i < 1000000000; i++) {
    d = ((double)((int)(1000000*a) % (int)(1000000*b)))/1000000;
  }
  result = time(NULL);
  printf("Time integer: [%s]\n", asctime(localtime(&result)));
```

I know, when `a` is negative, some more needs to be done, but at least for positive numbers, it gives a good performance boost (18 seconds instead of 110), but there is an obvious catch: in the example I've given, I've used `1000000` as an arbitrary number for multiplying in order to be sure that my numbers have no decimals anymore.

Is there some kind of function in the math library which gives me the size of the last decimal of a number? (hopefully a function that does not decreases the performance too much :-) )

Comment: Many decimal fractions turn into repeating floating point fractions, so there's no way to know how many decimal places there are.

Comment: Your limiting factor will most likely be based on `std::numeric_limits<int>::digits10` rather than only the actual digits within your float number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meanwhile I've found some other solutions to my problem: it seems that `fmod()` is a really slow function, and replacing it by something else is indeed a good idea, but there is no need to actual replace it by an integer calculation: simply creating a `#define fmod(a,b)  ((a) - ((int)((a)/(b))) * (b))` or creating an inline function, doing this calculation, already increases the behaviour significantly.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
if (a > 0)
     while (a >  b) a -= b;
else
     while (a < -b) a += b;
```

Comment: This is not a good idea: I would like increase performance, and though your algorithm looks correct, adding a loop is decreasing the performance (just imagine the case where `a=1000000` and `b=0.000001`).